# $elemMatch on array of objects

Tags: mongodb

My schema has 6 attributes of type Array, which can each contain objects, like this:

```js
alpha : Array
  0 : Object
    linkedID : "62495a66fb140b240476d8ff"
    verified : false
  1 : Object
    linkedID : "62494fd789291c4f58bdad86"
    verified : true
  ...
```

I want to write a query that returns a document where at least one of these Arrays contains an object that has the attribute `verified == false`. I've tried with `$elemMatch`:

```js
myModel.findOne(
  {$or: [
    { alpha: { $elemMatch: { verified: false } } },
    { beta: { $elemMatch: { verified: false } } },
    { gamma: { $elemMatch: { verified: false } } },
    { delta: { $elemMatch: { verified: false } } },
    { epsilon: { $elemMatch: { verified: false } } },
    { zeta: { $elemMatch: { verified: false } } }
  ] }
)
```

But this didn't work. I think this may be because it's a nested object, but I have no idea how to solve this. I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: your query is working properly https://mongoplayground.net/p/sYzL4m6WssR . please add some sample input data and desired output

Comment: If you need the whole document you dont need $elemMatch , you can just use the dot notation and search like $or:[ {"alpha.verified" : false },{"beta.verified":false}  ... etc. ] ...

Comment: Thank you @1sina1, I think I had a stray extra bracket somewhere, as it's working for me now that I copied your code